# Is it possible to trap hot air at 50 degrees for an year or more

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-storage

I have this question that has been running in my mind for days now. Lets say i have some air which i have heated to 50 degrees Celsius. Is there a storage mechanism i can lock this air in and store it for an year without dropping a degree for 1 year or more.

If yes,what material can store the hot air for that long?.

What i am looking for is not Ruthenium foils as that would be too cheap for my budget.

I am looking for a material that's pocket friendly,something practical.

Comment: In theory there's no reason to say that it's not possible with a good enough insulator: in practice, no such insulator exists. How to create such an insulator would be a question for chemistry or material science, not physics, so I believe this question to be off-topic.

Comment: @Asher - and yet materials-science is a tag here on Physics SE... But, even perfect vacuum would not suffice for this application, since radiative losses would kill you in any 'pocket-sized' object.

Comment: Another practical consideration is that, for air at atmospheric pressure, the heat capacity of an insulating spherical shell (to use the optimal shape for a thought experiment) will be far above the heat capacity of he air itself, unless you discover some new exotic insulator. So even if you find good thick insulation it will likely absorb a lot of that heat as it comes up to temperature. i don't even think aerogels would help much. Of course, if you are storing the air under extremely high pressure or in liquid form, then that would help a lot.

Comment: @Digiproc Is there a liquid that can maintain its temperature for an year and more?.

Comment: "Is there a liquid that can maintain its temperature for an year and more?" Yes, there are sous vide machines used for cooking which are basically small water ovens which can keep the temperature precisely fixed to a temperature to less than 0.25 Celsius. Beef short ribs cooked at 60 C for 72 hours turn out great. You could seal the air in a heretic container and then put it into a sous vide water bath. I think that bacteria may be able to grow at 50 C, though, so I would recommend a bit higher temperature. Look up "Sous Vide Supreme" on Amazon.com.

Comment: @SamuelWeir Thanks,thats new to me. I am also exploring generating some electricity in high pressure liquids or air.I am sort of blank on where i should start looking.

Comment: @JonCuster true, we do handle material science questions here... But not science fiction, which is where a container like what OP wants can be found.

Comment: @Asher - that is true. But you should complain as out the impossibility, not that it is materials science!

Comment: It depends in a large part on the temperature of the environment. If that is also at 50C, it is easy. If it is at minus 50C, it is considerably harder. The other factor is the size and pressure: if you have a very large sphere, it will take longer to cool down; if you pressurize the gas, its total heat capacity will increase. Finally, if you just make a double walled object and maintain the fluid between the walls at 50C, the problem also goes away. Such might be done with an appropriate wax that has a phase transition at 50C. As currently stated your question is too broad.